# how to get max id from master table and based on that insert one record in master table and one or more entry in child table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When I  click on <kbd>add</kbd> that data will go to child table and above data go to master table.

Here's a screenshot of the design:

[image]

save button click event:

```
 protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=GLSPL06-PC\GLSPL06;Initial Catalog=example;User ID=sa;Password=sa@123");
        con2.Open();
        SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand("insertmaster", con2);
        cd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text.Trim());
        cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtage.Text.Trim());
        cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Radiogender.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con2.Close();

        foreach (GridViewRow item in gv.Rows)
        {


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=GLSPL06-PC\GLSPL06;Initial Catalog=example;User ID=sa;Password=sa@123");
            con.Open();
            string statment = string.Format("insert into  child_table ( [relative_name], [relation]) values ('{0}','{1}')", item.Cells[0].Text, item.Cells[1].Text);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(statment, con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }

        successmsg.Text = "Data Inserted Successfully";
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide what you have tried till now and  where you are getting the problem/issue.  Stackoverflow is not the platform to provide readymade code/solutions !

Comment: @rohit i have edited please look out

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: i am not getting error

Comment: i just want to do this but i dont know how to implement this.

Comment: step-1: get max(pid) form Parent table. step-2: store in variable. step-3: insert this variable into child table

Comment: I think solution provided by Abhishesk Sharma is correct !

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Sql query as below in your procedure and call your procedure from application:

```
 DECLARE @id INT
    INSERT INTO MainPerson VALUES(Name,Age,Male)
    SET @id= SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    INSERT  INTO RelativePerson Values(@id,Name,Relation)
```

As you have to use the Scope_Identity in order to get the last id inserted to your master table.

Comment: i have used gridview to store the tempory data of the child table .

Comment: you have to use Stored procedure with User Defined Type as parameter to it and send your child table as parameter to Sp see the following Link:    [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412802/Sending-a-DataTable-to-a-Stored-Procedure)

Comment: but i dont know how to implement this in my project.

Comment: As First you have to insert using stored procedure in master table and select Scope_Identity() from there which you can get here using GetScalar() Method.

Comment: In your stored procedure **insertmaster** you have to select Scope_Indetity() at last after inserting query and use GetScalar() in code.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your code to this:

```
SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=GLSPL06-PC\GLSPL06;Initial Catalog=example;User ID=sa;Password=sa@123");
con2.Open();
SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand("insertmaster", con2);
cd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text.Trim());
cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", txtage.Text.Trim());
cd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", Radiogender.SelectedItem.ToString());
string id = cd.GetScalar();
con2.Close();
```

And Change Your **insertmaster** Procedure to:

```
Insert into MainTable values(name,age,gender)
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Then you will get the **id** use that to insert in child table from code.